# App store rejected App because of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, info.plist, capability

I will quote the apple document for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities which states :

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.
>
> If you use an array, the presence of a given key indicates the
>   corresponding feature is required. If you use a dictionary, you must
>   specify a Boolean value for each key. If the value of this key is
>   true, the feature is required. If the value of the key is false, the
>   feature must not be present on the device. In both cases, omitting a
>   key indicates that the feature is not required but that the app is
>   able to run if the feature is present
>
> **armv7** Include this key if your app is compiled only for the armv7
>   instruction set. **minimum ios version : iOS 3.1**
>
> **location-services** Include this key if your app requires (or
>   specifically prohibits) the ability to retrieve the device’s current
>   location using the Core Location framework. (This key refers to the
>   general location services feature. If you specifically need GPS-level
>   accuracy, you should also include the gps key.) **minimum ios version :  iOS 3.0**

[apple doc link for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

i have one key **armv7** in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array in info.plist for all my targets and **minimum ios version is set to 8.0**, **Supported Architectures : armv7, arm64** , **Required Capabilities : armv7 , App-Version : 1.0**

Now, i am using coreLocation Services for google map to find the lat- long of a place in the app. Do i need to add the **location-services** key also and will it help.

I am researching on this topic from days but can't find answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some confusion about valid architecture that my app should support. Firstly i deleted alamofire xcode project and added alamofire pod, this decreases plist numbers from 5 to 2 which was relieving.

Then i changed **targeted family from 1,2 to only 1** since my app was for iphone only.

**Deleted i386** architecture from valid architecture supported

If you'll check your project you will find various places to define deployment target. assign same deployment target throughout the app

Answer (score 2):

I would say you need at least the following capabilites:

`armv7`, `arm64`, `location-services` and `gps`.

Comment: do i need to add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities with your suggested keys in test target also ?

Comment: @Mr.bean Yep; I would give it a whirl.

Comment: the app is again rejected and on adding arm64 it was showing error